# Retrieve the contents of BPMN.xml file by deploymentID

Tags: activiti

i'm new with Activiti,  is it possible to retrieve the contents of BPMN.xml file from the deploymentID of a process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each version of process definition is stored in the DB as xml string. 
Yes it is possible.

you can use this:

```
InputStream xmlStream =  getRepositoryService().getResourceAsStream(deploymentID,resourceName);
```

or this:

```
// Fetch the resource
    String resourceName = processDefinitionEntity.getResourceName();
    ResourceEntity resource = commandContext.getResourceEntityManager()
            .findResourceByDeploymentIdAndResourceName(processDefinitionEntity.getDeploymentId(), resourceName);
```